# SQL query to get agreement list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some analytical data for different cases. Each case is associated with one or more photos. Each photo is analyzed by two users.
The stored data looks like 
[image: Source data]

What I want is to have SQL query to generate agreement result as shown below 
[image: Agreement result]

So, for case 17116 there is agreement on photo 175062 from user id 26 and 27. Similar case is with photo id 176031 from user id 24 and 29.

Can somebody help me out to achieve this.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Here is sample data to test with

Case Id,Photo Id,FeatureCheck,Result,CheckedBy 
17116,173442,severity,none,24 
17116,173442,severity,low,25 
17116,175062,severity,none,26 
17116,175062,severity,none,27 
17116,175427,severity,medium,24 
17116,175427,severity,high,28 
17116,175748,severity,low,22 
17116,175748,severity,none,30 
17116,176031,severity,low,24 
17116,176031,severity,low,29 
17277,175309,severity,none,24 
17277,175309,severity,none,25 
17277,175649,severity,none,24 
17277,175649,severity,none,25

Comment: you know that if you post your original/sorce table as text, it is simper to test, if someone has an idea to help you.

Comment: Sample data attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT caseid, photo_id , feature_check, agreedupon, 
   group_concat(checkedby SEPARATOR ',')  as listusers
FROM table1
GROUP BY case_id,  photo_id
```

Asssuming the possibility of more than 2 users checked the data. Then grouping them is more dynamic.

Comment: Great! This worked for me. Thanks @dodzb. Is it possible to get non-agreed also. If so can you just assist me.

Comment: Is it possible to get non-agreed data?

Comment: @IrfanRaza  How can this produce the expected result?

Comment: Atleast i got the users as comma separated list in a single column.

Comment: @IrfanRaza I think it is incorrect to mark an answer as accepted when it isn't the correct solution. This will only mislead others reading your question that are looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query:

```
select PhotoId,
       max(FeatureCheck),
       max(Result),
       max(CheckedBy),
       min(CheckedBy)
from MyTable
group by PhotoId
having count(distinct FeatureCheck) = 1
   and count(distinct Result) = 1
```