# SQL query to get user dis-agreements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some analytical data for different cases. Each case is associated with one or more photos. Each photo is analyzed by two users.
The stored data looks like 
[image: Source data]

What I want is to have SQL query to generate dis-agreement result as shown below

EITHER
[image: dis-agreement list-1]

OR
[image: dis-agreement list-2]

Can somebody help me out to achieve this.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Here is sample data to test with

```
Case Id,Photo Id,FeatureCheck,Result,CheckedBy 
17116,173442,severity,none,24 
17116,173442,severity,low,25 
17116,175062,severity,none,26 
17116,175062,severity,none,27 
17116,175427,severity,medium,24 
17116,175427,severity,high,28 
17116,175748,severity,low,22 
17116,175748,severity,none,30 
17116,176031,severity,low,24 
17116,176031,severity,low,29 
17277,175309,severity,none,24 
17277,175309,severity,none,25 
17277,175649,severity,none,24 
17277,175649,severity,none,25
```

Comment: Please explain how this is different from your previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57071431/sql-query-to-get-agreement-list.

Comment: Here i am finding such photos where reviews from two users are NOT matching. Earlier case is for getting photos with matching reviews. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ranjan for beautifying the tabular data, i was not able to figure out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
 t1.`Case Id`,  t1.`Photo Id`,t1.FeatureCheck,t1.CheckedBy,t1.Result,t2.CheckedBy,t2.Result
FROM test t1
 JOIN test t2
ON (t1.`Case Id`=t2.`Case Id` 
    AND  t1.`Photo Id`= t2.`Photo Id` 
    AND t1.CheckedBy!=t2.CheckedBy 
    AND t1.CheckedBy<t2.CheckedBy)
WHERE t1.Result!=t2.Result;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUZUSzqDsHbrJbvwo4RpoX/0)

Comment: Thanks all of you guys. This worked for me as the best solution. Thanks Mangesh.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

Key to the suggested solution is that you always have exactly 2 reviews to each combination of case, photo and feature.

Grouping by said combination you'll have groups with size of 2. Thus you get all users and results within a group by applying `MIN`/`MAX` to `result`/ `checkedby`.

What you need to check now is whether the minimum value of the user id and the minimum value of the result belong to the same record within a group. If they do, you're finished, otherwise you'd have to swap either user id or result. Equivalently to swapping you'd have to apply `MAX` instead of `MIN` and vice versa for the `result` field.

The check can be performed by computing the ranks within a group according to the user id and the review result and check whether they match in a given record or not. Note that the result of the matching predicate is constant in any given group. Thus we can add this predicate to the grouping criteria.

**Query 1 (requires Mysql 8)**

```
    SELECT caseid
         , photoid
         , featurecheck
         , MIN(checkedby)   user1
         , CASE reversal WHEN 0 THEN MIN(result) ELSE MAX(result) END review1
         , MAX(checkedby)   user2
         , CASE reversal WHEN 0 THEN MAX(result) ELSE MIN(result) END review2
      FROM (
                SELECT t.*
                     , CASE WHEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY caseid, photoid, featurecheck ORDER BY result) = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY caseid, photoid, featurecheck ORDER BY checkedby)
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                       END  reversal
                  FROM test t
           ) tbase
  GROUP BY caseid
         , photoid
         , featurecheck
         , reversal
    HAVING MIN(result) <> MAX(result)
         ;
```

`reversal` holds the prediacte mentioned in the *Approach* section, the having clause selects those cases where the reviews do not match.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKC1yN174P5NUc9sqo5u35/0) is a db fiddle.

**Query 2**

The use of the `RANK` function missing from earlier mysql versions can be simulated.

```
    SELECT caseid
         , photoid
         , featurecheck
         , MIN(checkedby)   user1
         , CASE MIN(reversal) WHEN 0 THEN MIN(result) ELSE MAX(result) END review1
         , MAX(checkedby)   user2
         , CASE MIN(reversal) WHEN 0 THEN MAX(result) ELSE MIN(result) END review2
      FROM (
                SELECT t1.*
                     , CASE
                        WHEN
                               (t1.cmin =  t1.checkedby AND t1.rmin =  t1.result)
                            OR (t1.cmin <> t1.checkedby AND t1.rmin <> t1.result)
                        THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                       END  reversal
                  FROM (
                            SELECT t.*
                                 , (SELECT MIN(checkedby) FROM test ts WHERE ts.caseid = t.caseid AND ts.photoid = t.photoid AND ts.featurecheck = t.featurecheck GROUP BY ts.caseid, ts.photoid, ts.featurecheck) cmin
                                 , (SELECT MIN(result)    FROM test ts WHERE ts.caseid = t.caseid AND ts.photoid = t.photoid AND ts.featurecheck = t.featurecheck GROUP BY ts.caseid, ts.photoid, ts.featurecheck) rmin
                              FROM test t
                       ) t1
           ) t2
  GROUP BY caseid
         , photoid
         , featurecheck
         , reversal
    HAVING MIN(result) <> MAX(result)
         ;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ucGxDUwdWzwvikZb7cBRwn/1) is a db fiddle.

Comment: @collpsar - thanks for detailed answer. Let me verify if this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING clause can give you the results you show.

```
SELECT  caseid, photo_id , feature_check, agreedupon
FROM table1
GROUP BY caseid,  photo_id, feature_check, agreedupon
HAVING count(agreedupon) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery to get the case_id & photo_id for which we have different results:

```
SELECT
    p.case_id,
    p.photo_id,
    p.feature_check,
    p.result,
    p.checked_by
FROM photos p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        case_id,
        photo_id,
        count(distinct result)
    FROM
        photos
    GROUP BY
        case_id,
        photo_id
    HAVING
        count(distinct result) > 1
) sub ON p.case_id = sub.case_id AND p.photo_id = sub.photo_id
;
```